# Adding bootstrap css for JSOUP converting HTML to PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, jsoup

I am trying to convert a HTML file to PDF using `JSOUP` and `xhtmlrenderer`.

Unfortunately the CSS ref links within the html are not able to be converted. The PDF generated is without any CSS...

Upon checking, there is a bootstrap CSS linkref added into the HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

please kindly let me know how to load this bootstrap CSS into `JSOUP` to be converted into PDF:

my code to convert html to PDF:

```
String inputFile = "d:\\contractorder-01.html";
String outputFile = "d:\\generated.pdf";

try {
    String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile)));
    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(document.html());
    renderer.layout();

    try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(outputFile))) {
        renderer.createPDF(os);
    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I've managed to generate the pdf, and passing values, using the `SpringTemplageEngine`. That allows me to use Thymeleaf to generate the `HTML` content, and you can pass also a `Context` (like the `ModelMap`), with the values:

```
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("name", value);
String html = templateEngine.process("application/pdf-agreement", context);
```

The `HTML` is a `thymeleaf` file, but the pdf resources need to be declared wherein the classpath is:

```
String filename = "filename.pdf";
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

renderer.setDocumentFromString(html,
                    new ClassPathResource("/pdf-resources/").getURL().toExternalForm());
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
renderer.finishPDF();
os.close();
```

But, the important thing is that `CSS3` is not fully supported and `CSS2` it's ok. But the only way to make it work was to use inline `css` defined at the `html` file.
Hope this helps.

---

OLD ANSWER

---

I have the same issue.
I've been following this [post](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/generating-pdf-documents-using-java-a29f90fbbd52).
If you look at the `PdfService`, the example it's done using a local resources folder, where all the CSS and JS are:

```
 private File renderPdf(String html) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = File.createTempFile("students", ".pdf");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer(20f * 4f / 3f, 20);
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html, new ClassPathResource(PDF_RESOURCES).getURL().toExternalForm());
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    file.deleteOnExit();
    return file;
}
```

The `PDF_RESOURCES` it's a folder that is placed at the `resources` folder.
Nevertheless, I've bee struggling that some CSS works, but no bootstrap.

I'll get back when I have better news.

Comment: Also forget to mention that the generated html was done using Thymeleaf.